# If there are no Posts displayed, how can I put a message?

Tags: python, django, authentication, post, blogs

In this situation I'm creating a blog, and in this blog I'm creating a "My Posts" page, and the thing is that if a user hasn't created a post, I want it to say the message "You have not written any posts yet", I'm having problems with the logic in the html, I was trying to use {% if post %}, but it's not working, here's the code:

my_posts.html

```
{% extends "app1/base.html" %}
{% block body_block %}


<div class="container">
<h1>Post</h1>
{% for post in object_list %}
{% empty %}
    <h1>You have not written any posts yet!</h1>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
{% if user.id == post.author.id %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'app1:article-detail' post.pk %}">{{post.title}}</a> -
    {{post.author}} - <small>{{post.post_date}}</small> - <small> category : <a href="{% url 'app1:category' post.category|slugify %}">{{post.category}}</a> - </small>
    <small><a href="{% url 'app1:updatepost' post.pk %}">Edit</a></small><small>
    <a href="{% url 'app1:deletepost' post.pk %}">- Delete</a>  
    </small></li>
    {{post.snippet}}
    {% endif %}
    {% endif %}

    
    



{% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
from .forms import  PostForm, PostUpdateForm
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Post, Category
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect



# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'app1/index.html')
    
def LikeView(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id = request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        liked = True
    
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app1:article-detail', args = [str(pk),]))


class PostView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'app1/post.html'
    ordering = ['-post_date']

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
        context = super(PostView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["cat_menu"] = cat_menu
        return context

def CategoryView(request, cats):
    category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category=cats.replace('-', ' '))
    return render(request, 'app1/categories.html', {'cats':cats.title().replace('-', ' '), 'category_posts': category_posts})

def CategoryListView(request):
    cat_menu_list = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'app1/category_list.html', {"cat_menu_list":cat_menu_list})

class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'app1/article_details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        context = super(ArticleDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        stuff = get_object_or_404(Post, id = self.kwargs['pk'])
        liked = False
        if stuff.likes.filter(id = self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True
        total_likes = stuff.total_likes()
        context["total_likes"] = total_likes
        context["liked"] = liked
        return context

class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'app1/createpost.html'
    #fields = '__all__'

class UpdatePostView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostUpdateForm
    template_name = 'app1/update_post.html'

class DeletePostView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'app1/delete_post.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

class AddCategoryView(CreateView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'app1/add_category.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('app1:Post')

class MyPostsView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'app1/my_posts.html'
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from datetime import datetime, date
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
# Create your models here.


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 255)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('index')

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null = True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField()
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null = True, blank = True, upload_to = "images/profile/")
    website_url = models.CharField(max_length= 255, blank = True, null = True)
    facebook_url = models.CharField(max_length= 255, blank = True, null = True)
    twitter_url = models.CharField(max_length= 255, blank = True, null = True)
    instagram_url = models.CharField(max_length= 255, blank = True, null = True)
    pinterest_url = models.CharField(max_length= 255, blank = True, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
        
    

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 255)
    header_image = models.ImageField(null = True, blank = True, upload_to = 'images/')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = RichTextField(blank = True, null = True)
    #body = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='coding')
    snippet = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'blog_posts')

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('app1:article-detail', args=(self.id,))
```

I would really appreciate your help and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `{% empty %}` tag in the for loop.

```
{% for post in object_list %}
...
{% empty %}
   <h1>You have not written any posts yet!</h1>
    
{% endfor %}
```

**OR** you can use simply the `if else` inside the template like this.

```
{% if object_list %}
{% for post in object_list %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
       <h1>You have not written any posts yet!</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Do I have to put it outside of the ifs? because it is asking for an else or elif

Comment: I updated it so you can see how I put it, but it still doesn't work

Comment: The message still doesn't display, I updated the code in the post so you can see if there are any errors